# How to derive a pdf of Complete Sufficient Statistic of exponential family

Tags: self-study, density-function, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, complete-statistics

[image]

While studying Mathematical statistics through "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 7th" (by Hogg and Craig), I've been stuck in the Theorem above.
The answer of the exercise 7.5.8 is not given in the manual solution and even not on Slader! "https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321795434-introduction-to-mathematical-statistics/401/"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and detail your attempt(s) at solving the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** the moment generating function is a natural tool for the study of exponential families.